# Custom blur function after Aurelia's validation

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am developing a SPA, using Aurelia Framework.

I have added a EventListener  to listen every input tag on blur event.

Inside that function I need to make an ajax call, which should be triggered only if input tag has passed all the validation rules.

```
document.addEventListener('blur', function (e: any) {
            if (e.target.dataset.inline && (e.target.value != e.target.defaultValue)) {
                var isValidTag = e.target.tagName === 'INPUT' || e.target.tagName === 'SELECT' ? true : false,
                    dataObject = _self.prepareObject(e.target.dataset.inline),
                    isInlineAllowed = isValidTag ? (dataObject && dataObject.isAllowed ? true : false) : false;
                if (isInlineAllowed) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        var hasError = e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("has-error");
                        if (hasError) {
                            console.log('Has Error');
                        }
                        else if (e.target.value != e.target.defaultValue) {
                            _self.peformAjaxCall(_self, e, dataObject);
                            e.target.className = e.target.className + ' highlightSuccess';
                            console.log('Saved');
                        }
                    }, 800);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Not Allowed');
                }
            }
        }, true);
```

Note:
My validation rules also triggers on blur event.

Is there any alternative way to remove to achieve this without any setTimeouts?

Thanks

Comment: you might simplify this with HTML 5 form validation. there are methods and hooks for checking validity [Form Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Comment: There is a validation plugin for Aurelia that works well. (https://github.com/aurelia/validation)  If you are building a new application, I recommend using it, instead of rolling your own validation that executes outside the Aurelia scope.  Using aurelia-specific plugins (especially ones that part of core Aurelia framework) are a good practice to help keep everything working together in unison.

Comment: @JosephGabriel I am using aurelia validations only.